# Inserting multiple json data into DynamoDB - Python (py)

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I **have 10k json files and i would like to insert them to Dynamo-DB** one by one i would love to get some help. **Python (py)**

> In all the json files the data are stored in the same format:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "582ff456aeddbf0ddcae6f58"
},
"product_filter": {
    "_id": {
        "Data_gender": "Women",
        ...
        ...
    }
},
"Data": {
    "AddDate": 1476546994,
    "fashionType": "Core",
    "Date": 123320000,
    "year": "2016",
    "brandDetailsEntry": {
        "id": 6746,
        "name": "lov me Weaves"
    },
    "id": 13132337,
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is the sample of my code what i am using**

```
import boto3
import json
import decimal

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('tshirts')
i=1
while i<20020:
    with open("data"+str(i)+".json") as json_file:
    x=json.load(json_file, parse_float = decimal.Decimal)
    # for j in x:
    #     product_filter = j['product_filter']
   print(x)
   data = table.put_item(
       Item={'product_filter': x})
   data.save()
   print i
i+=1
```

> i named my json files from 1 to 2000**

Comment: What is the problem? Have you resolved it yourself ? You should put your code and data in OP.